# Insert custom space into document

Tags: spacing, xetex

I want to insert a custom space at a given point. But am not sure how to implement it in the following MWE (needs to run in `XeLaTeX`).

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, fontsize=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=11.2cm, paperheight=17.4cm, top=1.6cm,bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\newlength\myspace
\setlength{\myspace}{\widthof{\normalsize{Help my of ek help myself.}}}
\showthe\myspace
\def\text{Text mooooved over here.}
\edef\abc{\text}
\abc
\end{document}
```

This is what I've tried but it doesn't work. Since the `\abc` is actually defined by `edef` outside in a `.sty`. file i can't add the `\hspace` immediately in front of the `\abc` as it would break the rest of my rather complex document.

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, fontsize=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=11.2cm, paperheight=17.4cm, top=1.6cm,bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\newlength\myspace
\setlength{\myspace}{\widthof{\normalsize{Help my of ek help myself.}}}
\showthe\myspace
\def\text{Text mooooved over here.}
\edef\abc{\hspace{\myspace}\text}
\abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\leavevmode\hphantom{\normalsize Help my...}`

Comment: There does not appear to be any dependency on xetex in either the question or example code.

Comment: The solution where this will be implemented will be run in XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `\edef` in a latex document, it is quite likely to break any commands in its argument, use `\def` or better `\newcommand`.

The reason the `\hspace` is not working is that white space is discarded at the beginning of a line: use `\hspace*{\myspace}` where the `*` preserves the space. Note that as it is the beginning of a paragraph you will also get paragraph indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Following David Carlisle's answer this is the working end result.

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, fontsize=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=11.2cm, paperheight=17.4cm, top=1.6cm,bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\newlength\myspace
\setlength{\myspace}{\widthof{\normalsize{Help my of ek help myself.}}}
\showthe\myspace
\def\text{Text mooooved over here.}
\newcommand{\abcd}{%
    \hspace*{\myspace}\text
}
\abcd
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\newcommand{\abcd}{%` or you will get a space that is too large by one inter-word space (if you ever use this command other than teh beginning of a line)